# Does Logback RollingFileAppender rename or truncate existing file

Tags: java, logback, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

Does logback `rename existing log files with a numerical suffix, then re-create the original empty log file` or `truncate the original log file in place after creating a copy`?

I am trying to use AWS Cloudwatch Agent with a Java application that uses logback. We currently using the `RollingFileAppender` with `FixedWindowRollingPolicy` and `SizedBasedTriggeringPolicy`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `RollingFileAppender` is a `FileAppender` which can rollover log files; this appender can log to a file named `myLog.log` and when a given condition is met change its target to another file. It has two required sub components:

- A `RollingPolicy` which performs the rollover
- A `TriggeringPolicy` which determines if and when a rollover occurs

That's the background, now, onto your question ... you wrote that you are using a `FixedWindowRollingPolicy` so when rollover occurs Logback will rename the `currentLogFle` as `currentLogFle1` and then create a new `currentLogFle` and this then becomes the active output target. So the answer to this question ...

> Does logback rename existing log files with a numerical suffix, then re-create the original empty log file or truncate the original log file in place after creating a copy?

... is:

> Logback will rename existing log files with a numerical suffix, then re-create the original empty log file.

There's a useful table [in the docs](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#FixedWindowRollingPolicy) describing this behaviour.